# Unfortunately the span do not render when i click on the button in Vue.js. What can I do?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem in Vue.js with conditional rendering. Unfortunately the span do not render when i click on the button. What can I do?

```
<v-btn icon @click="showInfo = !showInfo">
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>

      <span v-if="showInfo">Thats Information</span>
      <span v-else>That do not work</span>
```

and in the script:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    return: {
      showInfo: true,
    },
  }),
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Please create a reproduction of the problem? Here's a Vuetify template: https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/bgJOrX

Comment: Thanks @NoahStahl here ist the reproduction: https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/bgJOrX?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks, you'll need to save your changes as a new pen with a unique URL. That's the original.

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry @NoahStahl. Here: https://codepen.io/lukasluetke/pen/dyGQyBv?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

Try this data syntax instead of using the arrow function

```
data() {
  return {
    showInfo: true,
  }
},
```

This solve the problem for me in vuejs, i havent used vuetify so i'm sorry if this does not work

Comment: Data should be a plain object, like data: {
      showInfo: true,
  }

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link below, your problem was with data

Comment: https://codepen.io/hanigerges/pen/WNrYGOW?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be looking like this.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
      showInfo: true,
  }),
};
```